# How to avoid ordinal numbers when referring to a place in a queue?

Tags: phrasing, ordinal-numbers

I have the following sentence:

> "You are currently 5th in the queue"

I'd like to avoid using ordinal numbers. What is the best way to rephrase this sentence such that it conveys the same meaning, but doesn't use ordinal numbers?

Comment: I don't think this is possible if you want the precise position.

Comment: You are currently number five in line.

Comment: You are the person who is after the person who is after the person who is after the person is after the person who is after the beginning.

Comment: *You are in position five in the queue.*

Comment: There are 4 people ahead of you.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the ordinal? That seems an unreasonable restriction. It makes things that much easier with it. Is -th a problem to pronounce?

Comment: @Mitch: The number will be changed programmatically - it's difficult to properly use ordinal numbers in code, especially if it is to support internationalization

Comment: You are (currently is optional) the fifth person in the queue. If you're on the telephone: You are (currently) the fifth caller in the queue.

Comment: @Sue The question was about avoiding ordinal numbers like "fifth".

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for pointing that out. I mistakenly thought it was asking for a way to avoid numerals, not ordinals. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You might try:

There are four people ahead of you in line.
OR
There are four parties ahead of you in line.